# Execute script with transaction

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure to take a input script and upgrada tables. It also write into a table with update history. I wrapped them up with transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
PREPARE action from @upgradeScript;
EXECUTE action;
INSERT INTO database_history (version, changes)
VALUES (Version, comments);
COMMIT;
```

I set `@upgradeScript` to:

```
"ALTER TABLE t ADD column test1 varchar(45) NOT NULL;"
```

However, when the inset fails, it doesn't rollback changes in `@upgradeScript`.

I am wondering why and can anybody help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because 'ALTER TABLE' is a DDL statement which cannot be rolled back and implicitly ends a transaction.

More information -

- [Statements That Cannot Be Rolled Back](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-roll-back.html)
- [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html)

Comment: It's so sad. MS SQL Server support it. It's very useful when you change a database.